# 502 badgateway wcf doesn't respond

Tags: c#, wcf

We have created a wcf service, which takes the multiple line items gives us response, when there is 4-5 line items, It is working fine and giving response back.

when we are trying with more than 10 line items, we were getting 504 gateway time out error initially, then now 502 bad gateway error we are getting.

we tried giving Usedefaultproxy=null or false, but it doesn't help. Below the custom binding code. can anyone help me here.

customBinding

```
     binding name=CustomMapper UseDefaultWebProxy = null allowCookies=false maxBufferPoolSize=2147483647 maxBufferSize=2147483647 closeTimeout=00:15:00 openTimeout=00:15:00 receiveTimeout=00:15:00 sendTimeout=00:15:00


       webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="MyseOrdVerify.RawContentTypeMapper, MyseOrdVerify


     httpsTransport manualAddressing=true maxReceivedMessageSize=1524288000 transferMode=Streamed 


      binding
```

customBinding

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change the values of three properties:

maxConcurrentCalls, maxConcurrentInstances, and maxConcurrentSessions.

Try setting these values to be larger like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors >
      <serviceBehaviors >
        <behavior name="nettcpBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="MySessionBinding" />
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

</system.serviceModel>
```